kafka-streams does not add the right kafka-clients dependency
org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:jar:3.9.0 is suposed to use org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:3.9.0, but when I run mvn dependency:tree, I get
[INFO] +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:jar:3.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:3.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.luben:zstd-jni:jar:1.5.5-1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.lz4:lz4-java:jar:1.8.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.10.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.rocksdb:rocksdbjni:jar:7.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.15.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:jar:2.5.8-hadoop3:compile

My pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.0</version>
</dependency>

kafka-streams-3.9.0.pom
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
  <version>3.9.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>


Perhaps the pom.xml is explicitly using an old version?  Please update the question with the pom.xml file.

@AndrewS it's explicitly 3.9.0. I have updated the post.
